# Check user is logged in or not using Javascript

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, login, third-party-module, user

If user click on button in Product view page , we are redirecting to another url [ say 1.html] with help of js code :  `window.location.replace(responseData.redirect);`. But i want to redirect only if user is **Registered**.

**.js** :

```
_ajaxCreateImg: function(dataUrl, startNumber) 
{ 
    new Ajax.Request(this.createImgUrl, { 
        onComplete: function(response) { 
            var responseData = response.responseText.evalJSON(); 
            if(lastRequest == 1){ 
                this._processAjaxResponse(response); 
                window.location.replace(responseData.redirect); 
            } 
         }.bind(this) 
     }); 
},
```

Comment: How do you include this JS file? In config.xml in template-file?

Comment: @sv3n we have above code in `Js/Abstract.js` file ,  if user is logged in , we want to execute this code : `window.location.replace(responseData.redirect);` , otherwise not......

Comment: Question was how do you load `Js/Abstract.js`. Is it set in config.xml or in html code via `<script ...`?

Comment: @sv3n we have in 2 places : 1)config file :   `<action method="addJs"><script>aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/Editor/Tool/Abstract.js</script></action>`  2)template file : `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/Editor/Tool/Abstract.js')?>"></script>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would set a new variable in template file, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var isLoggedIn: <?php echo (int) Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ?>
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

And modify JS function like:

```
_ajaxCreateImg: function(dataUrl, startNumber) {
    new Ajax.Request(this.createImgUrl, {
        onComplete: function(response) {
            var responseData = response.responseText.evalJSON();
            if (lastRequest == 1) {
                this._processAjaxResponse(response);
                if (isLoggedIn == 1) { # added
                    window.location.replace(responseData.redirect);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass it through via require JS? Writing JS inside a template file seems wrong and not best practice.

Comment: @BenCrook Can you please post an example (or link to). I know there are different solutions like add an helper for `addItem` and check for logged in there, but then you have to split JS into serveral files to keep other funtionality for logged out users.

Comment: I'm 100% wrong as this is a Magento 1 question,  if it was Magento 2 this wouldn't of been best practice but for Magento 1 it's fine - I'm just an idiot :P